# Duplicating file with terminal, simply appending an increasing number

Tags: macos, duplicates, rename

I need to duplicate a video file many times before converting it. Problem is, on Mac, it adds some kind of text in the file name.

For example, my original file is named: 50.mp4, and after copy, it becomes Copy of 50.mp4, then Copy 2 of 50.mp4.

I would like to run a simple script to make around 20 or 25 duplicates (being able to change that from what I want), and I would like the different files to have names like `501.mp4`, `502.mp4`, `503.mp4` etc..

Answer (score 0):

**By using command:**

Open a terminal, `cd` to the location where the file is, then run command:

```
for ((i = 1; i <= 20; i++)); do if [ "$i" -gt 9 ]; then cp 50.mp4 5$i.mp4; else cp 50.mp4 50$i.mp4; fi ; done
```

To change the copy number, edit value of `i` variable in for loop.

**By using script:**

I wrote a simple bash script for this: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/KevCui/279379f1a6c415c208d44fe58c460a05/raw/68c7510540621dcdd8b85c49806ba0174424186e/copy.sh

Download this script to your local machine, the location where the file you want to copy is, then run command in terminal

```
chmod +x copy.sh
./copy.sh <filename>
```

In your case, to copy 50.mp4

```
chmod +x copy.sh
./copy.sh <filename>
```

By default, this script will create 20 copies of 50.mp4 in "duplication" folder, 501.mp4,...,510.mp4,...,520.mp4.

To change the copy number, edit value of `COPY_NUM` variable in script.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Gave it a try, and after 509, it's giving 5010 instead of 510. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @Vanity that's a new requirement... sure, it's possible, I did a quick-dirty fix in my answer above. Try it and let me know if it works or not.